# Set up env variable when sudo as apache user

Tags: centos

I have centos 7 webserser, all site's files within `\www\sitename\htdocs\` belong to user 'apache'.

Sometimes i need `git pull` as apache user, that's why i wrote simple script to sudo as apache:

```
[ansible@vm123123 ~]$ cat ~/suwu.sh
#!/bin/sh

sudo setfacl -m apache:x   $(dirname "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK")
sudo setfacl -m apache:rwx "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"

sudo -E su -s /bin/sh apache
[ansible@vm123123 ~]$
```

And it works well, i can log in as apache user, change files and forward my SSH key to git server.

But can't start `mc` as apache:

```
sh-4.2$ mc

(mc:36339): GLib-WARNING **: GError set over the top of a previous GError or uninitialized memory.
This indicates a bug in someone's code. You must ensure an error is NULL before it's set.
The overwriting error message was: Cannot create "/usr/share/httpd/.cache/mc"

(mc:36339): GLib-WARNING **: GError set over the top of a previous GError or uninitialized memory.
This indicates a bug in someone's code. You must ensure an error is NULL before it's set.
The overwriting error message was: Cannot create "/usr/share/httpd/.local/share/mc"
Сбой запуска:
Cannot create "/usr/share/httpd/.config/mc"
sh-4.2$
```

That's why i run mc like this:

```
sh-4.2$ MC_HOME=/tmp/MCHOME mc
```

This works, but is there a way to set up `MC_HOME` for apache once in my script or somewhere else?

Comment: You could add:  `export MC_HOME='/tmp/MCHOME'` to your `~/.bash_profile` or to the beginning of your script.

Comment: @Jesse_b user 'apache' has **no** home directory via security reason. Exporting variable in script is good idea, one minute...

Comment: If you aren't concerned with how it will affect other users on that machine you could add it to `/etc/profile`.  Maybe even an alias? `alias mca='MC_HOME=/tmp/MCHOME mc'`

Comment: @Jesse_b Yes, i know about aliases, byt I don't want this way. Exporting variable in script is working, thanks for solution (post it as answer)

Comment: My answer is a duplicate of several other answers on this site.  I am curious however if there is a "proper" way to set environmental variables for a user with no home directory.

Comment: @Jesse_b I am curious too. it's good question for https://security.stackexchange.com/ )) Exporting var in script is simple and practical, but in theory... curious, curious...